# Power Automate Flows - Filter Query not working as expected with multiple AND's

Tags: filter, powerapps, power-automate

The filter query in this flow doesn't appear to be working as expected. I know for certain that the items it emails out afterwards have the first two toggles set to false. Is there something in the syntax that I'm missing? Or possibly in the date/time comparisons? This is my first dive into Power Automate, and its with someone elses flow. So any insight is greatly appreciated.

[image: Filter Query]

This is an example of what it looks like after running, and getting items where Confirmed = false.

```
Thank_x0020_You_x0020_Sent eq 'false' and Confirmed eq 'true' and EventDate lt  '2021-07-20T00:00:00.0000000' and EventDate ge '2021-07-19'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two conditions are Yes/No Columns, so they need to be 0 or 1 (not true/false) Silly mistake, don't know how I missed that.

I agree with both previous comments for cleaning up the query in general.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `EventDate` is a DateTime data type, instead of the raw `outputs` try:

`formatDateTime(outputs('<actionName>'), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that having so many conditions for the query is not a good idea and less if dates are used.
It is better to do the query with one or two conditions and then filter the received data within an apply to each step